# Error in Updating the model from database (EntityFramework Database-First)

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-database-first

I know the reason for the following error very well,

> The specified type member 'Ticket' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

but the problem is that the property 'Ticket' is not calculated property or anything else, it is a normal field in the database, I am trying to read it.

I am using Database-first and the model was working in a wonderful way, but after I added this property to the database and "Update the Model from database" I started to receive this error?

What I missed in the "Update the Model from database" to deserve this problem?

Comment: [It's hard to answer a programming question without code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/), [Please include the minimum amount of code in your question needed to illustrate your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone faced the same problem. My problem was in the connection string

```
<add name="BT_IQMSEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/BT_IQMSEntities.csdl|res://*/BT_IQMSEntities.csdl|res://*/BT_IQMSEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=biteg-data;initial catalog=BT_IQMS;user id=sa;password=IWillNotShowYouMyPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Actually, the problem was in the three section 
`BT_IQMSEntities.csdl` 
`BT_IQMSEntities.csdl` 
`BT_IQMSEntities.msl` 
those sections must be the same as the name of the .edmx, and in my case the names where different from the .edmx name, and after fixing them and make them all the same, the problem solved.